# Adding data to existing table with primary key violates unique constraint despite being unique?

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I am attempting to add new data to the database I have created, however, I keep getting an error "ORA-00001" when adding to the table despite the data within the PK column being unique.

How am I able to add new data to the primary column, or do constraints need to be disabled every time?

I was attempting to do so via:

```
UPDATE Specialists 
SET Specialist_ID = 210000000005, 
    First_Name = 'Aaron', 
    Last_Name = 'Black', 
    Specialist_Category = 'Software', 
    Cases_In_Progress = 0;
```

I have Googled as specifically as I can to narrow down search results but I haven't been able to find the answer to just add new data into the PK column of an existing table.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This `UPDATE` will update and touch **every single row** in your table - is that really what you want? And since it's touching **every row** and setting each row's `Specialist_ID` (which I assume is the PK) to the **same value** - of course once it's done one row and comes around to the second,  you get that violation because you're trying to set the second row's `ID` value to 2100000005 again.....

Comment: No, I am just attempting to create a new specialist to go into the specialist table, not alter all hence the confusion, my last time doing so the command with the WHERE clause worked but Ive been away from it for a year so got some gaps to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

You code is clearly violating a `primary key` constraint.  That is for one of two reasons:

- There is already a row where the primary key has the value you are assigning it.
- Your update is updating more than one row.

I would go for the latter.

Assuming that `Specialist_ID` is the primary key, you may intend

```
UPDATE Specialists
    SET First_Name = 'Aaron',
        Last_Name = 'Black',
        Specialist_Category = 'Software',
        Cases_In_Progress = 0
    WHERE Specialist_ID = 210000000005;
```

In any case, a simple `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause is suspicious, because it updates all the rows in the table.

Comment: I attempted this before my bad forgot to mention it! It executes but no rows are updated and yes Specialist_ID is the primary key.